# Change sharing message to icons

Tags: feature-request, sharing

I find the "Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook." a bit messy. Could this be changed to the traditional sharing buttons that appear on a lot of websites today. I think it would give a more refined look to the sight.

Comment: @JoshC The icons would take up less space than all that text, and at this point it is very intuitive what those buttons would do, since they are everywhere. Would you agree?

Comment: I hate logos all over the place.  Keep it simple and clutter free.

Comment: Text is lighter than images

Comment: I would be happy to see those sharing buttons go away forever (and ever and ever)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Lets keep it the way it is.** As [@random states](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207289/change-sharing-message-to-icons#comment659619_207289), text is much lighter than images.

We should be looking to reduce the load on the server.. <sup>As I ironically post an image..</sup>

Would more icons be added, or would we just change the existing ones? Either way..

> [image]

Comment: You left out Digg. That's racist!

Comment: @Shog9 Digg is in there ^^ You probably didn't notice because they changed their logo.

Comment: My mistake; wasn't expecting blue for some reason.

Comment: @Shog9 A very relevant mistake, though--I think you just made a strong case for another reason why this suggestion shouldn't be implemented. :)

Comment: I don't see the OP suggesting we add any others.. Just convert the existing options to icons.

Answer (score 4):

We do already have icons in the "share" popup:

> [image: existing share dialog]

I don't think that looks cluttered.