# Text error at new unanswered questions

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions, spelling

I haven't noticed this before, so I don't know if this have always been like this or not.
But at a new question ([Bootstrap scrollspy and no rubber-band bounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965144/bootstrap-scrollspy-and-no-rubber-band-bounce)) which are currently unanswered, there is some text at the bottom that reads `Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, , , or .`
. I guess this is showing on new unanswered questions. At least I cant find it on any of my other questions.

It is a tiny problem, but the `, , , or .` part doesn't look good.

> [image]

Comment: Make a screenshot and share to confirm the bug.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the affected area

Comment: You block social plugins. Dupe, looking... found it.

Comment: Sorry.. I confirm that this problem goes away after disabling ad-block plus in Firefox.

Comment: @xeor no need to be sorry, it's good to report this.

Comment: Most of the people using Stackexchange are probably using an ad-block. Is this something to consider using an internal redirect to fix? Its not ads...

Comment: @xeor there's nothing Stack Exchange can do, it's 100% the adblock "fault" which is over aggressive. Most Stack Exchange can do if they really want to be friendly is showing a warning somewhere "we detected you have adBlock enabled, expect some design problems".

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was thinking about linking to stackoverflow.com/social-redirect/facebook/... and then do the redirect. Ad-block, as I understand block it because of where it links to. It is kinda dirty tho.. And ad-block might still block it.

Comment: @xeor no, that will be "too much" in my opinion. Better change it to icons instead of text so that when broken it won't be so ugly, think it was already proposed. Edit: [here it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207289/152859). Wasn't received very well!

Comment: @ShadowWizard good point, text is best in this case. And it is "too much" for such a small problem.. Thanks for commenting